# How to go to next textbox when enter is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys I'm learning Javascript and I would like to ask you guys how can I go to the next textbox after inputing text when I press the enter button in the keyboard. thank you

Comment: and what have you tried so far??

Comment: press tab and not enter :)

Comment: Try to read some books about, before trying something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.keyup()` to keep track of when user finish key in a character and `e.keyCode` to get which key was pressed, if it's `13`(*means enter*) then use `.focus()` to focus the next textbox element:

```
$('input[type="textbox"]').keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).next().focus();
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QRj83/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
 $('#inputform').on('keydown', 'input', function (event) {
  if (event.which == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(event.target);
    var index = parseFloat($this.attr('data-index'));
    $('[data-index="' + (index + 1).toString() + '"]').focus();
 }
```

});

Help [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/hxZSU/48/)

Comment: `event.which` isn't part of any specification, and although largely adopted, it's not in older IE. You should use `keyCode` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a plugin to include enter event.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.enter = function (func) {
        this.bind('keypress', function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) func.apply(this, [e]);
        });
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

You can call it like this:

```
$('#input1').enter(function(){ $(this).next().focus(); });
```

Comment: `next()` returns the next element sibling, which may not be the desired form field. I think a more consistent function should be provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the next field in many ways, as demonstrated by all the answers here, but don't forget to assign the order of what is actually NEXT as well. You can go from field to field with the TAB button, and the layout of your site may not always go in the order you'd expect or want. The solution to this is to add `tabindex=""` to your fields as such:

```
<input type="text" tabindex="1" />
<input type="password" tabindex="2" />
<input type="submit" value="Log In" tabindex="3" />
```