# Multiple input smoothly

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I need a form that have such a row need to be repeated multiple times. Row consist of text field, radio, checkbox, select box all types of input field. After typing first input field, cursor should be shown on next field by pressing just enter. Add button should be added to add each row. After submitting form data should be saved in mysql DB.

check the screenshot below : -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtKRM.png)

Comment: Please check this [article](http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/58/adding-unlimited-form-fields-with-jquery-mysql/).

Comment: thanks for sharing link, but this part is not solved in given link"cursor should be shown on next field by pressing just enter", so, please remove negative feedback (thumbs down) now

Comment: This article share concept  dynamically add field and submit value to mySql DB. Now regarding [cursor should be shown on next field by pressing just enter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511535/how-to-go-to-next-textbox-when-enter-is-pressed)

Comment: What did you mean by _so, please remove negative feedback (thumbs down) now_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used something like your requirement. Hope this become useful for you.

```
          <div class="form-group" id="text1">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Long/Lat</label>
            <div class="col-sm-7" id="p_scents1">
              <p>
                <!-- <div class="col-sm-6"> -->
                <input type="text" name="fname[]" id="fname" class="col-sm-3 form-control1" placeholder="Enter firstname">
                <!-- </div> -->
                <!-- <div class="col-sm-6"> -->
                <input type="text" name="lname[]" id="lname" class="col-sm-3 form-control1"   placeholder="Enter lastname">
                <!-- </div> -->
                <input type="text" name="location[]" id="location" class="col-sm-3 form-control2" placeholder="Enter location">
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <a href="#" id="addScnt1" >+ Add More</a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {        
//alert("hret");
    var scntDiv1 = $('#p_scents1');
    var i = $('#p_scents1 p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt1').live('click', function() {

            $('<p><input type="text" id="fname'+i+'" size="20" name="fname[]' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Enter firstname" class="col-sm-3 form-control1"/><input type="text" id="lname'+i+'" size="20" name="lname[]' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Enter lastname" class="col-sm-3 form-control1"/><input type="text" id="location'+i+'" name="location[]' + i +'" class="col-sm-3 form-control2" placeholder="Enter location"><a href="#" id="remScnt1">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv1);
            i++;
            return false;
    });

    $('#remScnt1').live('click', function() { 
      //alert(i);
            if( i > 2 ) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
                    i--;
            }
            return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Good luck!

Comment: thanks, but I want to dynamic  input,select box( that comes form mysql database) a row need to be repeated multiple times. i can't insert properly into database

Comment: use ajax to get data dynamically from database and add this code and that code together so you can fetch & add rows dynamically.

Comment: oh dude !! I need complete solution !!!!! I found all the codes you provided.

Comment: @RidwanulHoque You need a complete solution? Then code it yourself. Stack overflow is not a site where you get developers to do your work for free.

Comment: it's not a complete project, just a part that I need help for.